# regex to catch dollar amount catching @ symbol too

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match simple dollar strings ($34.21). My regex is as follows.

```
\$\d+.([0-9][0-9])
```

I'm catching the following string though and I don't know why.

```
@$23.23
```

Does the at symbol have some kind of special meaning? I don't see it on my regex cheat sheet and this is bugging me.

Thanks, mj

Comment: my data had the @ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the `\.` and you probably need to add start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around the pattern:

```
^\$\d+\.([0-9][0-9])$
```

The anchors are used to ensure that no other characters are allowed in the input string before or after the matched string.

Also, depending on the exact language / platform your using*, this can probably be further simplified to:

```
^\$\d+\.(\d\d)$
```

<sup>* Some regex engines treat `\d` as equivalent to `[0-9]`, while on others it will match any Unicode digit, including those from other numeral systems.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use line start and line end anchors to make sure you don't match unwanted input:

```
^\$\d+\.([0-9][0-9])$
```

OR

```
^\$\d+\.\d{1,2}$
```